# How do I migrate questions? (the option to migrate questions is gone)

Tags: support, status-bydesign, migration

Did something change with how to migrate questions to another stackoverflow website? The close reasons disappeared. Or is the ability to migrate questions gone now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, we just changed the workflow:

#### Step 1:

[image: offtopic]

#### Step 2:

[image: offtopic 2]

---

You see our dialog was not scaling to a ba-zillion close reasons. Migrated questions are always by-definition off-topic, so they get a new shiny area.

Comment: Nice - this looks much better

Comment: I could swear that it wasn't like that yet, when I asked the question (because I already thought something like this and changed every option). Well, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: The text to off-topic in step 1 really ought to give a hint about the possibility to migrate in step 2; this is by absolutely no means abvious from just seeing the step 1 page!

Comment: so, if I realize that my question is better on say serverfault, I must vote myself to close it and flag it as off-topic? No other self-humiliation steps? You guys are not creative enough. E.g. replacing my avatar with "I'm an idiot" is relevant too :)

Comment: What do I do if the question is already closed as off topic?

Comment: how do you migrate it to a site that doesn't show up in that list, for example drupal.stackexchange.com?

Comment: and to migrate to a site not on the list, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-to-migrate-question-to-programmers-stackexchange-com

Comment: When I click the "flag" link on a question, there is now no "off-topic" option, only the following: spam; rude or abusive; should be closed; a duplicate; very low quality; in need of moderator intervention. AFAICT, the correct workflow is now to click "should be closed > off-topic because". This then brings up a list of migration targets.