# How to migrate question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, migration

Faq says that you need 250 points to be able to vote for migration of questions, but still I don't see how to do that.

Comment: This really belongs on Meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should flag it as "it doesn't belong here". However, this question itself doesn't belong here (meta is a place for this kind of questions).

Comment: The way to do it is to flag the question for moderator attention.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question

Comment: very strongly related: **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**

Answer (score 30):

250 is the minimum reputation you need to vote to close/migrate your own questions. On Stack Overflow you have a reputation of 3000 necessary to vote to close/migrate any question.

If you want to migrate your own question, you click on *close*. (I took the screenshots on *Stack Overflow* on March 19, 2018.) On the dialog box that appears, click on *off-topic because...*.

> [image: screenshot]

In the next dialog box, click on *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*.

> [image: screenshot]

Then, on the next dialog box, you click on the site you want to migrate the question.

> [image: screenshot]

As per March 20018, *Software Engineering* is not listed as possible migration path. In this case, you could click on *flag*, and then report the reason to flag the question (e.g. *The question better suits XYZ*).

> [image: screenshot]

If you find a question asked from somebody else that needs to be migrated, then you click on *flag*, then on *in need of moderator intervention*, and report the reason you are flagging it.

> [image: screenshot]

This is still the way to report a question needs to be migrated to a site that is not reported in the list you see when you select *off topic*.

Notice also that it's not ANYMORE possible to migrate questions asked more than 60 days ago. In this case, clicking on *close* would give you the following dialog box.

> [image: screenshot]

As you see, the *off topic because...* option says *(too old to migrate)*. If then you click on that option, the next dialog would not show the *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* option.

> [image: screenshot]

In this case, flagging the question doesn't get any effect: Moderators would not be able to migrate the question, which can only be closed, if it's really off-topic for the site where it was asked, or if it is really a bad question.

What I reported is valid for the reputation you have on Stack Overflow. Once your reputation is at least 3000, you can vote to close any question; in that case, you don't need to flag a question to migrate it, except when the site where you think the question should be migrated is not listed under "off topic."

Comment: also there is a time limit for questions to be migrated. I flagged my question today to get attention and i got a response that "This question is too old to migrate to another site" [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830652/installing-sanyo-zio-usb-driver-on-vista-x64-now-my-phone-is-rooted-and-im-wi)