# Help me migrate my question to Code Review

Tags: support, migration, moderation, code-review-se

I have a [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025883/generic-wrapper-for-equality-and-hash-implementation-is-there-a-way-i-can-make) closed citing it's better suited for Code Review. How do I migrate it to that site? Can any moderator here do it for me? When I saw the "close" feature, in the "Off-topic" section, I could not see "Code Review" option there, so I couldn't vote myself for it.

Comment: This: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91397/196875. And this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/196875

Comment: Just flag it for a moderator's attention and go to *other* section and describe there to migrate it to Code Review (or XYZ.SE).

Comment: thanks @IceMAN and hims056, I will do it. I am voting myself to close this. If anyone of you can make it an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @nawfal: I think _hims056_ should be the one. He does explain the solution briefly. I merely link to existing ones. ;-)

Comment: @IceMAN in that case you have the right approach of a programmer. You're doing it very DRY and OOP :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flag it for a moderator's attention and go to *other* section and describe there to migrate it to Code Review (or XYZ.SE).